# How to return WireMock server port in a response body

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, wiremock

I have request which is returning WireMock URL to another WireMock stub.

U have a problem on CI tool port 8080 is taken so I have to use a random port. `@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)` ten port is random I am not able to mock port correctly.

I have mapping JSON with error:

```
{
  "priority": 1,
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/api/public/v3/tasks/taskid123"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "jsonBody": {
      "info": {
        "result_callbacks": [{
          "url": "http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port}/download/zip/result"
        }]
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }
  }
}
```

How to set server port in mapping JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (yet) grab the server port directly, but you can get the inbound port, which usually has the same effect:

`{{{request.requestLine.port}}}`

Comment: Does not work in response string i get string `{{{request.requestLine.port}}}` not an actual port

Answer (score 1):

**Attention!** don't forget add the  *"transformers": ["response-template"]*

```
"response": {
   ...
   "jsonBody": { "url": "http://localhost:{{port.request}}" },
   "transformers": ["response-template"]
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem thx to @Tom suggestion is:

```
{
  "priority": 1,
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/api/public/v3/tasks/taskid123"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "jsonBody": {
      "info": {
        "result_callbacks": [{
          "url": "http://localhost:{{request.requestLine.port}}/download/zip/result"
        }]
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "transformers": [
      "response-template"
    ]
  }
}
```